# Circumference of a superellipse?

Tags: integration, special-functions, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Could someone help me formulate the circumference of a superellipse? 
$$\frac{x^n}{a^n} + \frac{y^n}{b^n} = 1$$
If it makes things easier, I'm considering only the cases $n>2$, and $n\in\mathbb{Q}$. Since the formula for an ellipse ($n=2$) involves special functions, I assume the general case won't be any simpler, but I can't seem to find any sources on this.

I've also seen the circumference for an ellipse approximated by:
$$C \sim \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{a^2 + B^2}$$
Can this approximation be extended to the case of a superellipse, i.e:
$$C \sim A\sqrt{a^n + B^n}$$
Any help greatly appreciated.

[image]

**Edit:** Someone by the name of Maher Izzedin Aldaher [posted](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathforum.org%2Fkb%2Fservlet%2FJiveServlet%2Fdownload%2F13-2022730-7844987-765791%2Fxa.docx&ei=j2NwUdLUHqrIiwLOkoHABg&usg=AFQjCNEy773mprKu8gHUoW_3he2unHdPLw&sig2=XLwHcZDWEm4t3RQqU0DSdg&bvm=bv.45373924,d.cGE) some approximate numerical formulae online, one of them being:

$$4 \left[a+b \frac{ b\left(\frac{2.5}{n+0.5} \right)^{1/n} + \frac{0.566 a(n-1)}{n^2} }{b + \frac{4.5 a}{0.5+n^2}} \right]$$
I have no idea how this was derived or how good it is.

Comment: Then, an $n$-dimensional superellipse will be called a hypersuperellipse, which is much cooler.

Comment: There should probably be a $y^n$ in the first equation

Comment: @Joseph - thanks, fixed.

Comment: The formula there is not symmetric about $a,b$, this means if I interchanged them I'll get different result...  Do you know there's a general formula for the area of a superellipse, the one you have there you can approximate it by cutting it according to the grid of the graph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is taken up in detail in multiple sections [here](http://fractional-calculus.com/super_ellipse.pdf). See all the sections having to do with 'arc length'. This paper also goes through formulas for the area of such a figure, and other interesting properties. Enjoy. (Note: its not very easy stuff; as you pointed out, even the regular old ellipse's perimeter cannot be expressed in an elementary way, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html).)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know of either a closed form solution or alternatively a series in only one variable, say $a/b$?

Comment: I compiled a list of various papers and solved journal problems having to do with this sort of thing in the following [2 June 2007 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5754899), if anyone is interested.

Comment: @nbubis : I haven't seen any, sorry. Check out the papers in the comment above. Looks like you're gonna have to search deep for this one...

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro - didn't see anything over there about arc length. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nbubis: You're probably not missing anything. I didn't have time to look over it (I'm at work), but I figured even if arc length wasn't there (I would have guessed it was, but I suppose I would have guessed wrong), it might still be worth linking it here, since many of the items I cited are not easily found through usual literature searches (JSTOR, Math. Reviews, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

There's only general area formula for superellipse:

\begin{align}
  1 &=
  \left| \frac{x}{a} \right|^n+
  \left| \frac{y}{b} \right|^n \\
  A &= \frac{2ab}{n} \frac{\Gamma^2 \left( \dfrac{1}{n} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \dfrac{2}{n} \right)}
\end{align}

Only few cases for circumference are known:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  n & \text{perimeter} & \text{area} & \text{remark} \\ \hline \\
  \frac{1}{2} &
  \frac{4(a^3+b^3)}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{4a^2 b^2}{(a^2+b^2)^{3/2}}
  \left(
    \sinh^{-1} \frac{a}{b}+\sinh^{-1} \frac{b}{a}
  \right)
  & \frac{2ab}{3} & \text{4 parabolae} \\ \\
  \frac{2}{3} & \frac{4(a^2+ab+b^2)}{a+b} & \frac{3\pi ab}{8} & \text{an astroid} \\ \\
  1 & 4\sqrt{a^2+b^2} & 2ab & \text{a rhombus} \\ \\
  2 & 4aE \left( \sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}} \, \right) & \pi a b & \text{an ellipse} \\
  \\ \hline
\end{array}